# How to recreate EFI boot partition?

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, uefi

I've installed Fedora on my machine with `/` partition, `swap` partition and `ESP` partition for EFI booting.

Now, I was installing Elementary OS instead of Fedora.

1. I have formatted the `/` partition (/dev/sda3)
2. Formatted the swap partition (/dev/sda4)
3. But **did not** format the EFI boot partition (/dev/sda1)

Now when i boot, i get my old grub menu that's was installed by Fedora.
I can only boot into Elementary OS by:

1. Entering the boot menu.
2. Selecting boot from EFI file
3. Navigate through `/dev/sda1/`, to get the `elementary` directory that contains `grubx64.efi` file. Which is `/boot/efi/EFI/elementary/grubx64.efi`.

How can i fix that ? I thought of formatting the boot partition `/dev/sda1/` with `fat16` or something then re-installing grub on it.

My `/dev/sda1` now contains this :

```
root@rafael:/home/rafael# ls /boot/efi/
EFI  mach_kernel  System

root@rafael:/home/rafael# ls /boot/efi/EFI/
BOOT/       elementary/ fedora/     

root@rafael:/home/rafael# ls /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/
BOOT.CSV  fonts  gcdx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  MokManager.efi  shim.efi  shim-fedora.efi

root@rafael:/home/rafael# ls /boot/efi/EFI/elementary/
grubx64.efi
```

Here's my `efibootmgr` output :

```
BootCurrent: 003D
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Notebook Hard Drive
Boot0010* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive
Boot0011* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot0012* Fedora
Boot0013* Fedora
Boot0014* Fedora
Boot0015* Fedora
Boot0016* Fedora
Boot0017* Fedora
Boot0018* Fedora
Boot0019* Fedora
Boot001A* Fedora
Boot001B* Fedora
Boot001C* Fedora
Boot001D* Fedora
Boot001E* Fedora
Boot001F* elementary
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can only suggest this set of articles, never used EFI myself: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html, http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html, http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/whatsgpt.html.

Comment: Does your UEFI implementation have any kind of boot selection menu like F8 or so? Please post `efibootmgr` output so it could be seen whether elementary's entry is there (seems it's not but to be sure). You might also like [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as your boot manager. Just in case you'd like a quick peek at E17 on that system there's an [image that just works](http://nightly.altlinux.org/sisyphus/archive/regular-e17-20130227-x86_64.iso) (490M ISO link) as well as [weekly snapshots](http://nightly.altlinux.org/sisyphus/flavours/e17/). It is probably inferior regarding E polis

Comment: @MichaelShigorin Ok, I've added `efibootmgr` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it !

First of all, I removed all the unnecessary boot entries by:

```
efibootmgr -b <entry_hex_number> -B
```

Then, Reformatting the ESP partition with `FAT32` filesystem.

```
mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sda1
```

Then installed grub to `/dev/sda` NOT `/dev/sda1`

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: You don't need grub-install which writes MBR. I don't know if you distro's grub does the two things together, but what you need is to copy grubx64.efi (or shim.efi) to /boot/efi/EFI/$distro/ and efibootmgr -c -l /boot/efi/EFI/$distro/grubx64.efi.

Comment: grub-install has learned to grok EFI (you can force it to with --target=x86_64-efi but efivars.ko must be loaded by that time anyways).

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why you're using grub in the first place. UEFI acts as a boot
loader and it allows to select different operating systems or individual
kernels from a boot menu. Although there are some exceptions, it usually is
not required to chain a second boot loader, grub in this case.

You mention, you installed elementary OS *instead* of Fedora, which means you
only need to load *one* operating system. Here I present a way to do it
*without* using grub. The kernel needs to be compiled with
EFI_STUB, if that's the case you can check with

```
grep EFI_STUB /boot/config-<version>
```

#### Copy the kernel and initramfs to the ESP (EFI system partition)

```
cp /boot/vmlinuz-<version> /boot/efi/EFI/elementary/vmlinuz-<version>.efi
cp /boot/initrd.img-<version> /boot/efi/EFI/elementary/initrd.img-<version>
```

#### Register kernel as boot option in UEFI

```
echo "root=UUID=<disk_uuid> ro quiet rootfstype=ext4 add_efi_memmap initrd=\\EFI\\elementary\\initrd.img-<version>" |
  iconv -f ascii -t ucs2 |
  efibootmgr \
    --create --gpt \
    --disk /dev/<disk> --part <partition_number> \
    --label "Elementary OS" \
    --loader "\\EFI\\elementary\\vmlinuz-<version>.efi" \
    --write-signature --append-binary-args -
```

The `--disk` argument takes the device name of the disk, e.g.
`--disk /dev/sda`, the `--part` argument takes the partition number
of the ESP, e.g. 4. You can find the ESP partition number with the
following command:

```
gdisk -l /dev/sda | awk '$6=="EF00" {print $1}'
```

#### Ensure that you repeat the steps after each kernel update

Either you this manually (just repeat the steps above) or you write
a small script which does the job. To fully automatise it, the
script could be hooked into the kernel post-install procedure, into
the initramfs post-update procedure and into the kernel postrm
procedure (to remove the UEFI boot entry). Actually, I don't know
why this isn't done by default in the distributions, it's just a few
lines of code.

Comment: Hmmm, I did `grep EFI_STUB /boot/config-3.2.0-49-generic` but got nothing.

Comment: kernel 3.2 is too old (it's from January 2012) to support EFI_STUB. You need at least kernel 3.3.

Comment: @RafaelAdel If you don't want to build your own kernel you can check for a newer kernel version in the software repositories. Elementary seems to be based on Ubuntu and a kernel 3.5 or 3.8 should be available. The newer ones are more likely to have EFI_STUB enabled.

Comment: Actually there's kernel 3.10.1 now. Gonna give it a try.

Comment: Marco, advising stub use is *irresponsible* unless you're eager to guide each user through what's unsupported by his distribution and not pass it down like "do after each kernel upgrade".  It's fine to have but not so fine to automate, I'm telling you this as a guy who's responsible for UEFI support in ALT Linux.

Comment: @MichaelShigorin It's easy to hook it into `/etc/kernel/postinst.d`, `/etc/kernel/postrm.d` and `/etc/initramfs/post-update.d/`. The only thing the scripts need to do is copy/remove two files (kernel and initramfs) from `/boot` to the ESP and call `efibootmgr`.

Comment: So go ahead and implement it in debian at least.  BTW my *answer* is not a *comment* since it actually suggests refind (which tends to be an answer with crippled/missing boot menu in firmware or just broken/incomplete configuration).  Unfortunately short boot chains is not what UEFI is about in practice, especially with RestrictedBoot :-/

Comment: @MichaelShigorin I've been using Debian kernel with EFISTUB for a year and it's fine. Shorter boot chain is the point, because it gets rid of the bloated grub. I don't see how Secure Boot has anything to do here.